# Получения одного рандомного числа из вектора в R

Tags: случайные-числа, r, вектор

```
birth <- c(1960:1985)
BirthYear <- sample(birth, 20)
x <- BirthYear + 18
EmployYear <- c(x[1]:2006, x[2]:2006, x[3]:2006, x[4]:2006, x[5]:2006, x[6]:2006, x[7]:2006, x[8]:2006, x[9]:2006, x[10]:2006, x[11]:2006, x[12]:2006, x[13]:2006, x[14]:2006, x[15]:2006, x[16]:2006, x[17]:2006, x[18]:2006, x[19]:2006, x[20]:2006)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в векторе EmployYear было по одному числу из каждого мини-вектора (имею ввиду одно число из `x[1]:2006`, например).

Comment: `sample(вектор, количество)`

Answer (score 0):

вопрос, собственно, состоит из двух частей:

1. получить одно случайно выбранное число из диапазона значений `начало:конец` можно, например, с помощью функции [`sample()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/sample):

   ```r
   sample(100:200, 1)
   #> [1] 184
   ```
2. применить какую-нибудь функцию к каждому элементу вектора можно, например, с помощью функции [`sapply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/lapply):

   ```r
   вектор <- 1:5
   sapply(вектор, function(x) sample(x:10, 1))
   #> [1] 10 10  3  5  5
   ```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>